# Pandas aggregate by one column and take any random rows for the other columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a requirement where I want to group by one column of a pandas dataframe and take any random rows for the other columns. For example, the dataframe could be:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['p','q','r','r'],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':['l','m','n','o']})
Out[82]:
   a  b  c
0  p  1  l
1  q  2  m
2  r  3  n
3  r  4  o
```

And the output I require (one possibility):

```
 Out[83]:
   a  b  c
0  p  1  l
1  q  2  m
2  r  3  n
```

Note that the last rows could have been "r 4 o" as well but not "r 3 0". I need the entire row to be taken. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `groupby().sample`:

```
df.groupby('a').sample(n=1)
```

If that doesn't work, then you can shuffle and drop duplicates:

```
df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates('a')
```

Sample output:

```
    a   b   c
0   p   1   l
1   q   2   m
3   r   4   o
```

Comment: The first one didn't work, second one did. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @RohitPandey You're welcome. The first one  was [introduced](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) in Pandas Version 1.1.0. If you have early version, then it wouldn't work.